# Swagger showing "Found unknown parameters" error

Tags: java, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I tried to create stubs for sample swagger specification as mentioned in [Swagger CodeGen Documentation](http://swagger.io/docs/swagger-tools/#swagger-codegen-documentation-9), but it  does not work as intended to.

```
Exception in thread "main" 
io.airlift.airline.ParseArgumentsUnexpectedException:
Found unexpected parameters: [-i, http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json, -l, java]  at io.airlift.airline.Cli.validate(Cli.java:148)
 at io.airlift.airline.Cli.parse(Cli.java:116)
 at io.airlift.airline.Cli.parse(Cli.java:97)
 at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:36)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of this issue on [Swagger Documentation for creating server stub](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Server-stub-generator-HOWTO#java-jax-rs-20-spec)
documentation page.

Below is the command in case the link is obsolete or does not work :

```
java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-2.2.1.jar generate -i http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json -l java
```

Comment: You should include what you consider is the solution in case the link stops working in the future.